# Netbeans C code format

Tags: c, netbeans

I am using NetBeans for my C coding and I would like to know how to change the format for it. I would like it to appear like this when I pres enter for a new line:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

int x;

void xzy()
  {

}

printf("etc...etc..etc..");

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Basically to the point where everything starts at the beginning of the line rather than this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

         int x;
         void xzy(){

    }
         printf("etc...etc..etc..");

        return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: So you want to not indent your code? I hope no one else ever has to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I consider that what you are trying to do will make the code very unreadable and it goes against the standards. But if you really want to do it, here is what I found:

In NeatBeans, go to `Tools > Options`. The `Options` window will pop up. Click `Editor` and then select the `Formatting` tab. In the `Language` dropdown, select `C`. In the `Category` dropdown, select `Formatting Style`. Check the option `Override Global Options`. Then bellow set the property `Indent Size` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly what you mean since your sample code doesn't display correctly as currently formatted, but it sounds like you want to turn off the auto-indent feature.  To my knowledge, there's no way to completely disable the auto-indent in NetBeans.  You can adjust the size of the indent and the indentation style used, but you can't completely turn it off.  If you play around with the code formatting options for a while, you may be able to get something that's similar to what you want.

As a side-note, this is not the best forum for asking this sort of question.  You'll likely get a much better response by using the NetBeans forum/mailing list.